# Using Page Anchors In Primary Site Navigation

Tags: url, anchor

So I have a basic (Wordpress powered) portfolio site where most of the content lives on the homepage, and then I'm using a custom posts category for the featured projects, so users can click through and get more info on the project at its category-single.php page. So the idea is it's a pretty flat site in terms of structure.

So flat, in fact, that the site navigation in the header simply links to content that is all on the home page (About, Work, What, Contact are all sections on the home page that get scrolled down to when you click).

What I want to happen is when the user is on the home page, and clicks one of the top nav links, the page scrolls down to that section (no problem here - I've got this part working just fine), and then when the user is on another page of the site (think one level deep, a custom post page) if they click the header nav links it returns them to the homepage and scrolls them down to that section. I'm thinking in terms of basic url anchor structure, like http://somesite.com/page#specific_section where that link takes the user to a specific section on somesite.com/page.

However the trouble I seem to be having is with creating these url's correctly. I've written them as mysite.com#about, mysite.com#work, mysite.com#contact, mysite.com#page-top, but instead of trigging the user to go to the homepage, the browser is interpreting those links as instructions to look for those sections on the current page.

What am I doing wrong, and what is the correct way to accomplish this?

The thing I'm trying to consider additionally, is whether I need to create PHP logic that displays the links one way on the homepage, and another way on the rest of the site.

Comment: Turns out the issue is my jQuery scroll plugin is disabling the link function. Ha.

Comment: That's... really bizarre and counterintuitive. Would love to hear about the issue because I'm implementing a JS scroller and that sounds like exactly the kind of dumb crap I'd like to skip an hour debugging.

Comment: Yeah the plugin requires me to add a class of "scroll" to the links that I want to scroll down to a section, so I guess it disables the default linking behavior on said links and listens for the click event, then scrolls the user down to that section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is use the actual filenames of the pages in question, like:

`mysite.com/aboutme.html#qualifications`
`mysite.com/portfolio.html#ZirTech

For links to the homepage, try either using the root relative path or fully qualifying the link like so:

`http://www.mysite.com/#section` *fully qualified*

`/#section` *relative path*

You shouldn't need to implement them a different way on the homepage - just implement them properly throughout the site.

Answer (score 1):

When you write the URLs as mysite.com#work, mysite.com#contact, mysite.com#page-top the browser looks for the page in question, because it is not instructed to go to another page (you need to add "/" to redirect it).

If you want them to point to the main page, set them as

```
mysite.com/index.php#work, mysite.com/index.php#contact, mysite.com/index.php#page-top
```

Maybe it is possible without `index.php`, but I'm a bit lazy to test now:

```
mysite.com/#work, mysite.com/#contact, mysite.com/#page-top
```